# Django form.clean() run before field validators

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms, django-validation

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/

States that `run_validators()` is run before the form subclass’s `clean()`.

My model looks like:

```
def validate_ascii(value):
    try:
        value.encode('ascii')
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        raise ValidationError("Contains non-ascii characters")

class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, validators=[validate_ascii])
```

In my form's `clean()` method

```
class KeywordAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Keyword

    def clean(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        cleaned_data = super(KeywordAdminForm, self).clean()
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        return super(KeywordAdminForm, self).clean()
```

After that, the validators for each field in the form is run. This is causing issues because my clean method assumes each field has had the `validator` run first and crashes.

Why is my form's `clean()` method being run before the validators on the field?

Answer (score 3):

Change your forms `clean()` method to call `cleaned_data = super(KeywordAdminForm, self).clean()` first before performing the rest of your validation. [This is how the docs recommend you do it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

[This section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform) has an explanation for your issue.

> Model validation (Model.full_clean()) is triggered from within the
> form validation step, right after the form’s clean() method is called.

This would suggest that you cannot rely on any model validation in your clean method

Comment: Thanks, this has the same result. When I try this solution for both nested inline forms and the top base form, they both only call the validators after the my clean function (which now calls ```cleaned_data = super(YourModelForm, self).clean()```) has finished. I'll have another closer look at the documentation as well check if the nested forms do anything different.

Comment: I've modified it (original question updated with complete code) to be the most basic example that should work, but it is still running ```clean``` before the validator

Comment: The first argument to `super` in most cases should be the same class as the second argument. In this case `super(KeywordAdminForm, self)`

Comment: Thanks, I copied it in wrong. It is still invoking clean before my validation code(); I've placed a breakpoint in the validate_ascii function and it only gets there after the clean function has finished.

Comment: This section of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform) has an explanation for your issue. "Model validation (Model.full_clean()) is triggered from within the form validation step, right after the form’s clean() method is called.". This would suggest that you cannot rely on any model validation in your `clean` method

Comment: 1 solution would be to move your `clean` method from your form to your model

Comment: hhmm, I -do- believe I have used all the validation mechanisms correctly, do you see anything I have done wrong?
In link in your answer, it says "By the time the form’s clean() method is called, all the individual field clean methods will have been run." which is basically exactly the behaviour I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123370/discussion-between-a-g-and-iain-shelvington).

Comment: Hi @IainShelvington, can you edit your answer to include your comment referring to the order of the triggers? Thanks! For some reason, I am unable to edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to "[Validation on a ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform)" paragraph of the docs:

> There are two main steps involved in validating a ModelForm:
>
> 1. Validating the form
> 2. Validating the model instance

This defines that there are two completely different layers of validation, one in the model level and one in the form level.

Therefore it is clearly wrong to expect that these layers of validation are somehow related.

- However, there is a sound solution as described in the ["Overriding the Default Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)" paragraph of the same chapter:

  > If you want to specify a field’s validators, you can do so by defining
  >   the field declaratively and setting its validators parameter.

  Your example could become:

  ```
  from django.forms import CharField, ModelForm
  from myapp.models import Keyword

  class KeywordAdminForm(ModelForm):
      slug = CharField(max_length=50, validators=[validate_ascii])

      class Meta:
          model = Keyword
          fields = '__all__'
  ```

  Bear in mind though to read the green "Note" that follows this example which  states that:

  > Similarly, fields defined declaratively do not draw their attributes
  >   like `max_length` or `required` from the corresponding model. If you want
  >   to maintain the behavior specified in the model, you must set the
  >   relevant arguments explicitly when declaring the form field.
- Alternatively, you can do something like this:

  ```
  from django.forms import CharField, ModelForm
  from myapp.models import Keyword, validate_ascii

  class KeywordAdminForm(ModelForm):
      def clean_slug(self):
          slug = self.cleaned_data.get('slug')
          validate_ascii(slug)
          return slug

      def clean(self):
          cleaned_data = super().clean()
          if self.errors:
              return cleaned_data
          ...
          return cleaned_data

      class Meta:
          model = Keyword
          fields = '__all__'
  ```

  The above code works because it potentially raises a `ValidationError` inside   `clean_<field>()` that is called before `clean()`.